# Eclipse behavior on Linux when shared by multiple users

Tags: linux, eclipse, permissions, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

We are trying to setup Eclipse in a shared environment, i.e., it will be installed on a Linux server and each user connects to it using remote X. There are different reasons for sharing Eclipse, one being proper integration with ClearCase.

Our admin has setup eclipse with some default plugins and each user accesses eclipse thru remote X. Now, I wanted to install a new plugin so that it can be used by everyone. After installing the plugin, it's accessible to me only, it's not available for others. However, the plugins installed by admin are available to everyone.

When looked, the plugin installed by me and the plugin installed by admin are at different location:

plugin installed by me:

> /home/ernesto/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_53742576/plugins/

where /home/ernesto/ is my home directory.

plugin installed by admin:

> /project/eclipse/plugins/

where /project/eclipse is eclipse installation directory

Is it due to permissions? Is this behavior documented somewhere?

I am using eclipse juno 4.2, it's SuSE Linux server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. It's due to permission restriction.

You can find detail information from [Eclipse's documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html).

**Note:** There are a lot of existing known [defects](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358471) in this scenario.